# What is wrong in the following conditional expression in bash?

Tags: bash, comparison, conditional-statements

What is wrong in the following conditional expression in bash?

```
if [[ -z $x -o $x -ge 100 -o $x -le -100 ]]; then
        echo $x "\t" $i
fi
```

I get the following error
syntax error in conditional expression
syntax error near -o

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just use `||` like this:

```
if [[ -z $x || $x -ge 100 || $x -le -100 ]]; then
```

the `[` is a synonym for test -- in fact, in some systems, /bin/[ points to /bin/test:

```
$ which [
/usr/local/bin/[
```

the `-o` flag for test does OR

the `-o` flag for `[[` (the bash builtin) checks if a shell option is set [e.g. `-o vi` for vi editing]

Comment: Right. I can. I was just wondering in general why -o for OR doesn't work.

Comment: addressing your question in my edit -- for some raeson i cant do multiline comments (basically it has a different meaning because bash interprets it differently)

Comment: In Bash, `type -a [` will give you "[ is a shell builtin: and "[ is /usr/bin/[".

Comment: @Dennis Historically it was a separate command (for the original shell).  Note that according to the posix standard it is still supposed to be a separate command: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html

Comment: @Foo Bah: I didn't dispute that. My point was that `type -a` is more useful than `which`.

Comment: @Dennis what is the difference between `which` and `type -p`

Comment: If `type -t` doesn't return "file", then `type -p` returns nothing`. `type -P` (capital "P") is comparable to `which`.